# ios - c file log message

Tags: ios, c, printf, nslog

I have a ios application which has some C files. I would like it to printed in the console.

I would like to log messages and print the value of an unsigned int inside the C file in the console.

NSLog and printf doesn't work, is there a way to do this ?

Or is there any work around ?

Comment: You can use normal C language printf statements, like printf("my text %d", anyInt);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for OS X apps. It might work for iOS also.

```
#include <syslog.h>

syslog(LOG_WARNING, "Log me to console");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried fprintf instead of printf?

```
unsigned int err;
fprintf(stderr, "Error: %u", err);
```